# how to convert velocity map to fluid flow map

Tags: python, simulation, fluid-dynamics

It may be a very simple question, if you have the answer please share.

**Provided** a series (say for `t0..tn`) of the matrices (`2D` arrays) of velocities in `X` and `Y` directions `(UX,UY)` by means of application of [Lattice Boltzmann method (LBM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_Boltzmann_methods) on the simulation of fluid flow in 2D, **the question** is how to make an animation of fluid flow.

We should be able to use velocities to find positions of **(??)** by applying: `Position = Velocity x Time`. Any ideas of what could be **(??)**.

We think that we could have a same size of velocity matrix of particles for time `t0` and find the next position matrix as mentioned above, so to move particles accordingly.

- Please share your knowledge!
- Is the chosen approach correct?
- Any other methods etc etc.
- For this problem tips in Python are more than welcome!
- Pseudo-codes could be of more help!

---

To simplify the question the following is the velocity map at time `tn`, trying to have a fluid flow map based on that, **How?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the initial distribution of your particles is fairly regular (a grid, or uniformly random), you'll find that after a while all the particles tend to cluster together, leaving entire areas of your fluid empty and thus invisible.

I found that a good method is to have short-lived particles (on the order of seconds). When a particle dies, it is respawned in a random position. Also, because each particle traces only a short path, the accuracy of the integration method used doesn't matter so much: a midpoint method or even forward Euler does the job just fine.

Comment: We just started trying some simple implementation of LBM for fluid flow modeling. The code found generates velocity map (`quiver`). How to make a fluid flow simulation (mass transport~particle move etc) based on it? Any simple `Python` working code or pseudo-code? There are resources on web freely available to be studied for background, of course. That's so good but there is no simple working (no dependency to other libraries)! Any help/idea/comment!